# Searching content by hashtag on current account on Instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, tags, instagram

My test business account currently has 4 images, 2 of which have the #test hashtag. I first queried the hashtag ID with:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/ig_hashtag_search?user_id={uid}&q=test&access_token={access_token}

The result was "17841563557120538"

I then proceeded to query my account with:

> graph.facebook.com/17841563557120538/recent_media?user_id={uid}&fields=id,media_type&access_token={access_token}

It returned images several results that aren't mine. I verified that the {uid} belongs to my account.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You misunderstood this endpoint’s purpose. _“Returns a list of the most recently published photo and video IG Media objects published with a specific hashtag.”_ - it is not supposed to search in the posts of a particular account. The `user_id` parameter is “the ID of the IG User _performing_ the query”, so that the results can be tailored to them individually (like prioritize posts made by accounts they are following, stuff like that.)

Comment: Hehe I was wondering why I "recent_media" was there. Thanks